# What incentives are there for using Flex over plain AS3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm a flash programmer and the only incentive I have to use Flex, as opposed to plain AS3, is to more easily get clients - not too great of an incentive in my eyes.

Can someone give an example application where I'd be better off using Flex instead of plain AS3? Also, what general incentives are there for using Flex?

Answer (score 6):

I think benefits of Flex over straight ActionScript:

1) **A Default Component Set**:  If you're building an application that needs Comboboxes, lists, and DataGrids; then Flex is a great choice.  These are a bunch of components designed to work together and have a consistent API.

2) **A Component Framework**:  The Flex Framework includes a framework for building new components, laying out those components, styling those components, and managing the application's visual state.  If you need this, you'll probably save a lot of time using an existing one over creating your own.

3) **Tooling**: Flash Builder and Flash Catalyst, built specifically for building Flex applications.  The proper tooling can provide significant time savings with many projects.  The Flex Profiler and Flex Debugger are two great examples of things that have saved many countless hours in debugging and tuning Flex applications.

4) **MXML** MXML is a declarative languages, similar to HTML and is great for laying out your application quickly.  Under the hood, MXML is turned into ActionScript by the Flex Compiler, and I once heard MXML described as an ActionScript code generation language.  The declarative approach makes layout easier.

5) **Open Source**: Flex is open source, so you have all of the source code to the Flex Framework, the Flex Compiler, and others.

6) **Community Support**:  There are tons of Flex Components extending the Flex Framework, there are other frameworks for MVC and Dependency Injenction.  There are unit testing frameworks and tools to automate the testing of your applications UI.  If you need these things, they are there for you.

There are some things to think about.  Not all may apply in your specific case; and there may be equally valid reasons not to choose Flex (such as performance).  I personally think "job/contract/employment" prospects is a very compelling reason to learn something, but on such things I tend to be a capitalist.

Comment: I'm out to murder Flex so bear with me. 1) If my app has a lot of ui components then why not use HTML instead of a swf? 2) This sounds like a good reason - but I've heard that the code is horrid/bloated. Isn't the datagrid 15k lines of code? 3) It sounds like these features mainly exist to compensate for Flex's shortcomings. 4) I'm not very familiar with MXML. It sounds overly complicated. If I know AS3 why wouldn't I just write the AS3?

Comment: 1)One could reformulate your question: why use Flash technology at all?Without getting in a philosophical argument HTML vs Flash, if you are set to use Flash, then you can ponder Flash vs Flex. 2)Code might be bloated, but it is an official framework. That gives companies the chance to recruit knowing that candidates know it and won't have to learn a new framework.3)Don't understand that point.4)It is a new markup you need to learn. At the end of the day, it is still better than HTML in the sense that you don't have to worry about cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: As for why not just write the AS3 instead of using Flex, I think the reasons provided do summarize why you could choose Flex over Flash. I personally don't use Flex for the only reason that I dislike Eclipse, and also I guess for the type of projects I do. Maybe as an individual I'm making a different decision than that I would make if it was in the context of a big organization.

Comment: I find MXML inherently useless, because you don't have as much freedom in stylizing your ui. The main reason I think most people choose flash, is because of it's sheer power to realize any visual idea. For example say I want a login button to be tweened from upState to hoverState, how would I do that? You won't be able to easily do that, so why not just use a simple as3 project?

Again like I said, I never liked MXML so I didn't go too much in depth with it, maybe I'm wrong, and it is actually easy to do these things, but I think as3 projects on flashBuilder work just fine for me.

Comment: I'd also like to add that there's CSS support, Component states, skinning (this is a huge one, try to skin an AS3 component with reusable code).  The charting components are bloated, but they're also old; Adobe's currently working on it and will hopefully be released soon for Spark.  If you want to sum it up in one line why use Flex: "It's faster."  Plain and simple.  I cut down my development time by half by using Flex and doubled my salary in the process...

Comment: @vvMINOvv you can style your app however you want or use Flash components within MXML it all comes down to learning the SDK and understanding how it works. @Ryan Working with MXML is in many ways much more straight forward than working HTML / CSS again you just need to learn it. It is not that painful to work without Flash Builder or Flash Catalyst. Simply using TextMate ANT and the free Flex compiler is a valid workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Flex provides you with a robust application and layout framework. So I would probably use Flex if:

- your app uses many standard controls
- you're creating an application with forms
- your application has many pages with varying layouts
- your app requires validation on forms
- your app requires re-skinning
- your app has datagrids in it
- you want to use an MVC framework that requires it such as Mate

I would probably use flash if:

- you are creating an app that has heaps of strong complex animation and limited functionality
- you are extremely concerned about bandwidth
- you are creating ad banners

Remember Flex is a subset of Flash and you can do pretty much everything in Flex that you can do in Flash except for timeline animation.

Comment: Most of your Flex reasons are also reasons as to why one would use HTML/CSS/Javascript instead of swfs. For example, if I had to use a lot of forms then it is a no brainer to use HTML forms. You make Flex sound like an improper substitue for HTML web apps as opposed to a valid substitute for swf apps.

Comment: Stop making this about HTML.  The argument is about using Actionscript VS Flex.  If you want to make it about HTML, create another question.  Also, don't ask a question and then completely dismiss any answers that might be given.  Flex is made for rapid RIA development while creating a great UX with code that is easy to manage and debug with a buttload of tools and libraries to support it.  If you think what you're trying to accomplish is better with HTML/JS, then go that route.

Answer (score 0):

[Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#) - Lots of examples

[Class documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/class-summary.html) - Full class listing

If none of those examples look useful and you think you have no use for any of the classes (at least in the mx and spark packages), then by all means, don't use Flex.